# MySQL fix Error Code: 1175 without disabling safe mode

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a simple stored procedure to update a single value in one of my tables.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_user_email`(in id int, in email varchar(255))
BEGIN
    update `user`
    set
    `email` = email,
    `modifiedOn` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    where `id` = id;
END
```

But when I attempt to execute it to test I'm getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.
```

How can I resolve this issue WITHOUT disabling safe mode?

```
To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.
```

Answer (score 0):

It was way harder to track down a way around this as 90%+ of all posts simply tell people to turn off safe mode. However I found a work around.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_user_email`(in id int, in email varchar(255))
BEGIN
    update `user` u  /* added identifier "u" */
    set
    u.`email` = email,
    u.`modifiedOn` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    where u.`id` = id; /* reference the pk column with the identifier */
END
```

I simply added what I'm going to refer to as a reference to the table (please tell me if there's a more appropriate term)

Comment: You should not give parameters the same names as columns

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. I will keep that in mind